# iOS - Can we do drag and drop between two separate collection view?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, drag-and-drop, uicollectionviewcell

I am having a nested collection view inside collection view cells, can I perform drag and drop from nested collection cells to another nested collection cells?

Comment: Yes you can do that ... using DragDropDelegate

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good [Tutorial](https://github.com/pgpt10/DragAndDrop-CollectionView) how you can achieve drag drop within `collectionView` also drag drop in different collectionViews